# Google Scripts: "Too complex regexp"

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

A function that I was testing had been working every single day up until now, when the console returned

```
  "Error: Too complex regexp."
```

Now, granted, the regex is long:

```
titleList = titleList.join("|");
var reg = "("+titleList+")?( )?\\d+[ab]?(:\\d+(-\\d+)?)?";
```

where `titleList` is an array of some 200-odd values. The regular expression checks a portion of text to find something like "De Vita Caesarium 7:14", where the "De Vita Caesarium" is from a list of titles.

However, this regular expression has been working fine until today. Did the restrictions set by Google Scripts change? If so, how can I modify the expression without running into the error?

Comment: Is there a new title with a character that needs to be escaped?

Comment: ^^ what Juan said, by far the most likely explanation. [This question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) may be useful for dealing with that.

Comment: Tried using a function to escape all the title, and yet the problem persisted. I even checked the titleList again (on the website that it is pulled from), and it doesn't have any characters that need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/cm_regex.html) explains that:

**Complexity (Component) Limitations**

> To ensure that content filters with regular expressions do not cause processing delays for your email, Content Manager limits the complexity of regular expressions. A regular expression can have up to 100 components. Content Manager considers each special character, character set, and string of literal characters as a separate component. For example, the regex \Wc[i|!]alis\W contains the following 9 components: \W , c , [ , i , | , ! , ] , alis , \W

I can only guess that Google app scripts have a similar restriction. You likely have more titles than you used to. If you test again with a hardcoded number of titles (fewer) and it works, you know that's the restriction.